# dplyr negative select if df not null

Tags: r, dplyr

I run an api extract each morning. There is a variable `bla` that may or may not be null. If it's not null it is a dataframe that contains a field `sessions`, in which case I would like to deselect sessions.

Normally, `bla` is indeed a dataframe and not null and the following block runs fine:

```
bla |> ... dplyr chain here ... |> select(-sessions)
```

But in those cases where bla is just null, I need this code to still run and not buckle my workflow.

Tried:

```
bla |> ... dplyr chain here ... |> select(!any_of('sessions'))
```

But this errors with:

```
Error in UseMethod("select") : 
  no applicable method for 'select' applied to an object of class "NULL"
```

How can I tell dply to run the select command only if bla is not null?

Comment: Are you sure this is having a problem.  it works fine for me `head(iris) |> select(!any_of('sessions'))|> nrow()
[1] 6`

Comment: But what is head(iris) is not a dataframe and is just NULL?

Comment: i.e. yes it works if I'm starting with a df, but if the df is null I need to be able to tell r just to skip it

Comment: Can you wrap in `tryCatch` i.e. `tryCatch(head(bla) |> select(!any_of('sessions')) |> nrow(), error = function(e) NULL)#
NULL#`

Comment: Can you use `exists` or `tryCatch` as in the solution posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of ways to deal with this.  Use an `if` condition on `exists` (if we have created an object earlier in the step)

```
library(dplyr)
if(exists('bla')) {
      bla |> 
       select(!any_of('sessions'))
  }
```

---

Or wrap with `tryCatch`

```
tryCatch(bla |> 
      select(!any_of('sessions')), error = function(e) NULL)
```

---

Based on the OP's update in comments, if this is part of a chain, we can check if the number of rows are greater than 0 before we `select`

```
ab_tests <- get_ga_df(viewId, c(start_date, end_date), ab_metrics, ab_dims) %>%  
     index_zen_name(dimension_lookup_marketing) %>%    
    dedup_key(c('session_id', 'date')) %>%  {  
      if(!is.null(.)) {          
        select(., !any_of('sessions'))
       } else .
   }
```

Comment: WOuld it be possibel to get this running at the end of a dplyr chain where the if(exists)) part would be against the dot .? e.g. something like `NULL |> if(exists(.) ...`

Comment: Because this part is at the end of a dplyr chain and it's only on this last step this error sometimes occurs since it's on the last step the resulting df within the chain may or may not be NULL

Comment: `>   ab_tests = get_ga_df(viewId, c(start_date, end_date), ab_metrics, ab_dims) %>% 
+     index_zen_name(dimension_lookup_marketing) %>% 
+     dedup_key(c('session_id', 'date')) %>% 
+     tryCatch(select(!any_of('sessions')), error = function(e) NULL)
Error: `any_of()` must be used within a *selecting* function.
ℹ See <https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/faq-selection-context.html>.`

Comment: `>   ab_tests = get_ga_df(viewId, c(start_date, end_date), ab_metrics, ab_dims) %>% 
+     index_zen_name(dimension_lookup_marketing) %>% 
+     dedup_key(c('session_id', 'date')) %>% 
+     if(nrow(.) > 0 ) {select(!any_of('sessions'))}

Error in if (.) nrow(.) > 0 else { : argument is of length zero`